# What happens to the Great Ravens once the Crippled God is gone/dead?

Tags: malazan

We see that the Great Ravens sacrifice themselves to form the Crippled God's body. Is there any indication that any or all the Great Ravens survived?

Answer (score 1):

I think that if any of them would survived they'd either behave like a "normal" great raven without a master/purpose and became sorta wild or they'd go to their last master.

Well...

> Anomander Rake is dead

but Anomandris  (Im not 100% sure if i got the right name) took after him, so ravens could've go to him to serv him in the black coral or just go there to take shelter/live there because andi are quite a "magical" race.

Still we don't get any evidence that any of them survived. I think that some of them should have. Why? Well they have to guard coltains soul or his vessel (i guesse).

*I have found errors in my answer. Great ravens are not the same as  Crows guarding vicans souls.
I started reading again from the begining and I didn't really found anything related to what could happened to great ravens afterwhole action with chained god. But as I mentioned earlier if any survived they'd propably go to black coral. And I think Andarist was cousin of Anomander not Anomandris (Anomander is propably the same person as Anomandris I just rememered those two names and I thought that they belonged to two different Andi). I'll fix my answer if I'll find any more errors.*

Comment: I am re-reading the whole series as well, currently at "Toll the Hounds", so not at the last book yet to give some insight. But regarding Anomander and Anomandris, they are the same person. I think it is just a shorthand for his full name: Anomandaris Dragnipurake. Even though the wiki just mentions it as a pseudonym: http://malazan.wikia.com/wiki/Anomander_Rake

Comment: After Rakes death his cousin took role of king/ruler of Tiste Andi and Black Coral. And I remember that his name was similar to Rakes but Im not 100% sure right now if he was called Andarist either. I have to read it more careful (still have some pages before me though...).

Comment: Andarist was his brother but was killed by Edur on Trift Avali. His son took over: Nimander Golit. http://malazan.wikia.com/wiki/Nimander_Golit

Comment: Now that I finished "The Crippled God" again as well, I am also rather convinced that all ravens sacrificed themselves to rebuild the body. The crippled god ordered the ravens to eat his scattered pieces of flesh when he first crashed into the world.